# Vagrant Windows 10 box does not reset evaluation days remaining

Tags: windows, windows-10, vagrant

My trial/evaluation Windows 10 box in Vagrant does not reset the days remaining of the trial every time I `vagrant destroy` then `vagrant up` or when I uninstall Vagrant/Virtualbox and delete local boxes and VMs and recreate them:

[Screenshot of the Windows 10 evaluation watermark bottom right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acdVp.png)

I'm under the assumption that Vagrant takes a "box" which is just an archive of a virtual machine and some config, makes a copy of it, extracts it then registers it for other Vagrantfiles to consume.

If this is true, shouldn't something like a Windows 10 trial always reset? Mine is not and the days remaining keeps going down no matter how much I try to start again so I will inevitably have to manually reset the days remaining via commands or use a different box.